# How do I set the initial state of a keras.layers.RNN instance?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I have created a stacked keras decoder model using the following loop:

```
# Create the encoder
# Define an input sequence.
encoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, num_input_features))

# Create a list of RNN Cells, these are then concatenated into a single layer with the RNN layer.
encoder_cells = []
for hidden_neurons in hparams['encoder_hidden_layers']:
    encoder_cells.append(keras.layers.GRUCell(hidden_neurons,
                                              kernel_regularizer=regulariser,
                                              recurrent_regularizer=regulariser,
                                              bias_regularizer=regulariser))

encoder = keras.layers.RNN(encoder_cells, return_state=True)

encoder_outputs_and_states = encoder(encoder_inputs)

# Discard encoder outputs and only keep the states. The outputs are of no interest to us, the encoder's job is to create 
# a state describing the input sequence.
encoder_states = encoder_outputs_and_states[1:]
print(encoder_states)
if hparams['encoder_hidden_layers'][-1] != hparams['decoder_hidden_layers'][0]:
    encoder_states = Dense(hparams['decoder_hidden_layers'][0])(encoder_states[-1])

# Create the decoder, the decoder input will be set to zero
decoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 1))

decoder_cells = []
for hidden_neurons in hparams['decoder_hidden_layers']:
    decoder_cells.append(keras.layers.GRUCell(hidden_neurons,
                                              kernel_regularizer=regulariser,
                                              recurrent_regularizer=regulariser,
                                              bias_regularizer=regulariser))

decoder = keras.layers.RNN(decoder_cells, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)

# Set the initial state of the decoder to be the output state of the encoder. his is the fundamental part of the 
# encoder-decoder.
decoder_outputs_and_states = decoder(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)

# Only select the output of the decoder (not the states)
decoder_outputs = decoder_outputs_and_states[0]

# Apply a dense layer with linear activation to set output to correct dimension and scale (tanh is default activation for
# GRU in Keras
decoder_dense = keras.layers.Dense(num_output_features,
                                   activation='linear',
                                   kernel_regularizer=regulariser,
                                   bias_regularizer=regulariser)

decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs=decoder_outputs)
model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss=loss)
model.summary()
```

This setup works when I have a single layer encoder and a single layer decoder where the number of neurons is the same.  However it does not work when the number of layers of the decoder is more than one.

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=[InputSpec(shape=(None, 48), ndim=2)]; however `cell.state_size` is (48, 58)
```

My decoder_layers list contains the entries [48, 58].  Therefore my RNN layer that the decoder is comprised of, is a stacked GRU where the first GRU contains 48 neurons and the second contains 58.  I would like to set the initial state of the first GRU.  I run the states through a Dense layer so that the shape is compatible with the first layer of the decoder.  The error message indicates that I am trying to set the initial state of both the first layer and the second layer when I pass the initial state keyword to the decoder RNN layer.  Is this correct behaviour?  Normally I would set the initial state of the first decoder layer (not built using a cell structure like this) which then would just feed it's inputs into subsequent layers.  Is there a way to achieve such behaviour in keras by default when creating a keras.layers.RNN from a list of GRUCell of LSTMCells?

Comment: I ran into this issue today, did you get any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In my own experiments, your `intial_states` should have batch_size as its first dimension. In other words, each element in one batch may have a different initial state. From your code, I think you missed this dimension.